# itunes search whith white spaces

Tags: javascript, titanium, itunes-store

I am working on creating direct links to the itunes store with any given song that is on a radio station. I was having some trouble dealing with white spaces and was wondering if you could help.
I'm using javascript, so the structure of my 'grab' button event listener is as follows:

```
grabButton.addEventListener("click", function (e){

    test= streamer.getMetaTitle();// returns a string such as 'Nirvana - Polly'
    artistTest = test.substring(0, test.indexOf("-"));
    titleTest = test.substring(test.indexOf("-")+1, test.length);
    var punctuationlessA = artistTest.replace(/[\.,'-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
    var punctuationlessT= titleTest.replace(/[\.,'-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
    itunesSearch= "http://itunes.com/"+punctuationlessA+"/"+punctuationlessT;
    Titanium.Platform.openURL(itunesSearch.split(' ').join(''));

});
```

The question really is what do I replace white spaces with in the last line of the event listener? As of now, if there are no spaces in a song or artist name, it works and avoiding punctuation seems to have worked also. Any help appreciated!

Comment: So what is your question? Code which you wrote works, the only thing which I would change is instead of `split(' ').join('')` just use `replace(/\s/g, '')`

Comment: @daniula I need to replace the white spaces with 'something', but I didn't know what. If there are white spaces then the link isn't valid and wont direct to the itunes store. So I was asking what I needed to replace the white spaces with

Comment: http://itunes.com/nirvana/liveatreading works. Can you send example link which doesn't work after removing whitespaces?